# MapKit transit view

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm looking for a way to display the transit/subway lines in a MapKit view. I'd basically like the [same view as the "Transit" view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBODg.jpg) in the Maps application. I can't find the right overlay or map type. Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solutions for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Transit map type is not available yet. You might have to customize your own mapView.

Comment: Where is in the Apple documentation that it's not available yet?